# Reading filepath from properties file

Tags: java, file-io, properties

I'm trying to read a file from a filepath read from properties, but I keep getting FileNotFoundException (the file exists).

test.properties:

```
test.value = "src/main/resources/File.csv"
```

LoadProperties.java:

```
public class LoadProperties {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

      Properties aProp = new Properties();
      aProp.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/test.properties")); // works

      String filepath = aProp.getProperty("test.value");
      System.out.println(filepath); // outputs: "src/main/resources/File.csv"

      FileReader aReader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/File.csv"); // works
      FileReader aReader2 = new FileReader(filepath); // java.io.FileNotFoundException
   }
}
```

Why is this exception being thrown while the line above it works just fine?
How should I read a file from a path provided with properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to put " in your property file. Here Java sees it as :

```
String file = "\"src/main/resources/File.csv\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test.value =src/main/resources/File.csv
```

You don't need double quotes in properties file to represent a continuous string.

Answer (score 0):

you can write own logic to read properties file, it does not matter whether single quotes or double quotes are there in the file path

```
String propertyFileLocation = "C:\a\b\c\abc.properties";
try
    {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(propertyFileLocation);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        properties = new Properties();
        String currentLine = null;
        String[] keyValueArray = null;
        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!currentLine.trim().startsWith("#")) {
                keyValueArray = currentLine.split("=");
                if (keyValueArray.length > 1) {
                    properties.put(keyValueArray[0].trim(), keyValueArray[1].trim().replace("\\\\","\\"));
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
```